# unable to send keys with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, web-crawler

element

```
<input id="mainframe.childframe.form.div_main.form.div_work.form.edt_applicantMgmtName:input" class="nexainput" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:173px;height:26px;" value="예: 홍길동" type="text" data-security="on" tk_security="true">
```

my code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="예: 홍길동"]').send_keys(name)
```

but it keep clicking the element only. and element look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87ClJ.png)

[image]

what should i do?

Comment: Can you post the link? and more of your code

Comment: Try clear the input first and then send keys or use Actions class or you can try with jsexecutor.

Comment: @mkhurmi oh thanks i fixed it by your advice

Comment: I am glad it worked. Now i will post my above comment as answer. Please double check it as mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the webElement and then send char sequence in the text field.

```
ele.clear()
ele.sendkeys("text to send")
```

If that doesn't work try using ActionChains to perform Mouse & Keyboard actions by keyboard actions- click, Ctrl + A, Delete and then send char sequence. Something like this:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(ele).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("Keys.Delete").send_keys("your-text").perform
```